# How to access Office 365 Calendar? (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit)

Tags: firefox, email, calendar, microsoft-office

I got some serious trouble with Office 365 Calendar.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as Operating System.

I used to use Office Online or [Hiri](https://www.hiri.com/) to access my Outlook 365 Account (Exchange), but since yesterday, Outlook Online doesn't load the calendar and since today, Hiri doesn't load the calendar either! Email does work online and via Hiri, but I cannot connect to my calendar!

I access Outlook Online with latest Firefox. In my security options I have whitelisted any URL that I could find that outlook tries to connect to (see list below) and still get some errors and warnings in the console (see below).

Firefox console output:

```
Content Security Policy: Unbekannte Direktive 'prefetch-src' kann nicht verarbeitet werden
Content Security Policy: Die Direktive 'child-src' sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Bitte verwenden Sie stattdessen die Direktive 'worker-src' zum Kontrollieren von Workern bzw. die Direktive 'frame-src' zum Kontrollieren von Frames.
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Wurzel-Element gefunden
Adresse: https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/view/bootr.ashx?bret=ok&cId=2A44B55E20AD40A09D8789E51AA37CC1&csev=AM6PR08MB5237&dag=EURPR08DG050&fost=eurprd08&dring=WW&app=Calendar&cver=2019042903.10&csver=19.4.29.2&fe=AM5PR0102CA0023&be=AM6PR08MB5237&cbe=AM6PR08MB5237.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com&wsver=15.20.1878.21&te=0&puid=10032000456BE3C5&tid=96117401-498a-4c8f-b649-f89b94dabdf1&mbx=c6d9970c-6f34-4edd-9d59-87757dc0f5dc&prem=0&fs=1557389685563&pref=-1&dls=196&dle=211&cs=212&ce=288&scs=235&reqs=288&ress=313&rese=339&doml=328&domcles=2841&domclee=2933&domc=2954&les=2954&lee=2954&nt=0&redc=0&pe=2385&pltnav=4959&pltnonav=4483
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1: bootr.ashx:1:1
Content Security Policy: "'unsafe-inline'" wird innerhalb von script-src oder style-src ignoriert: nonce-source oder hash-source angegeben
Content Security Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf inline blockiert ("default-src"). TokenFactoryIframe:1:1
Content Security Policy: "'unsafe-inline'" wird innerhalb von script-src oder style-src ignoriert: nonce-source oder hash-source angegeben
Content Security Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf inline blockiert ("default-src"). TokenFactoryIframe:1:1
Content Security Policy: "'unsafe-inline'" wird innerhalb von script-src oder style-src ignoriert: nonce-source oder hash-source angegeben
Content Security Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf inline blockiert ("default-src"). TokenFactoryIframe:1:1
```

I have no clue where I can get rid of these content security policy stuff. :(

Whitelist for cookie and website data in my firefox settings:

```
https://shellprod.msocdn.com [ALLOW]
https://webshell.suite.office.com [ALLOW]
https://graph.microsoft.com [ALLOW]
https://login.microsoftonline.com [ALLOW]
https://substrate.office.com [ALLOW]
https://outlook.office365.com [ALLOW]
https://ocws.officeapps.live.com [ALLOW]
https://management.azure.com [ALLOW]
https://officeapps.live.com [ALLOW]
https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com [ALLOW]
```

Any advice on how to be able to use my calenar again is appreciated!

Comment: You haven't linked your question in anyway to Ubuntu (or an official flavor of Ubuntu), which is what the site rules require.  (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit, sry I didn't mentioned this. I wil edit my question accordingly

Comment: Try the Google Chrome browser, and should that work, try the Chromium browser.

Comment: Google Chrome doesn‘t work either. I haven‘t tested chromium yet. I will update my question later and inclusive these information.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary approach I've found is to disable the "try the new Office" switch at the upper right on Office Online. Seems like the old version of Office Online does work just fine on Ubuntu Firefox, whereas the new edition doesn't work at all!

**Update at May, 10:**

The calendar works again in any browser (tested in Firefox, Chrome and Chromium). I assume, that it was a bug on their web application which they fixed. Thank you, Microsoft! :)